# Computing letter coordinates (Typesetters Steganography)

Tags: formatting, positioning, dvi, steganography

Is there a way to find out about the coordinates of letters in a formatted piece of text?

Suppose the compiled text has three columns, and the letters are equally spaced. Then what I'm looking for is a command that decides, depending on its (row, column) coordinates, if a letter is printed bold, or not.

---

Probably things are getting clearer if I explain what it's used for. It's some sort of superimposed ASCII image, hidden in a text. When reading the text, you may notice that some characters are printed bold, some are not, in a seemingly random fashion.

When looking at the text from a distance, you see the big picture.

An example: [image]

The dots represent regular text, while the `s' are a stand-in for bold characters.

The main challenge is that it needs to be a multi-column text which makes it harder to tell which characters need to be printed bold.

---

I'm heading towards using `dvitype` for my needs.
But does anybody know what, e.g.

```
131: setchar72 h:=1310720+491521=1802241, hh:=114
```

might encode? What I do know is that `72` represents `H` according to ASCII which is the first letter of the `Hello World!` tex file

```
Hello World!
\bye
```

But what's the meaning of the other digits?

Comment: You need to clarify how you expect this to be achieved since I am having to guess you mean in the PDF (fit for printing)  which would not be "fixed" until finally saved as complete. Thus post TeX processing phases. The final position is stored in the pdf in a variety of ways some with coordinates and some without coordinates thus an external editor type application is probably necessary to do that type of query. What TeX post processing can do is consider the saving format (say decrypted) such that an external app can do easy stream extraction. It may be possible in TeX to do that using DVI ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @KJO! If I got you correctly, there is no way of getting that information at compile time. What I want to achieve is a superimposed image on a poster size text, s.t. the image can be seen from a distance. Purely by means of printing decided characters bold.

Comment: I'm still unclear of your intended workflow , in TeX you can mix (overlay) text and image but primarily as a typesetting application text is usually small point sizes say 8 - 20 pt and some can readily be emboldened but that natively would not be well suited to mechanisation. Although it can be scaled up for poster or presentation usage. we would likely need to know how tex is being used (by a MWE Minimal Working Example) in order to provide suitable solutions

Comment: That's much better to visualise, so the main question now is are the characters already set (OCR solution) or are you wanting to generate such subliminal patterns, which although a challenge possibly could be created by TeX given the right parameters of base text and overlay characterisation

Comment: The characters are not set yet. It would be great to pass a bit pattern of the image, and the (generic) text would be formatted accordingly.

Comment: This is a typical form of printers stenography https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Printed I am sure I saw Printed examples exactly as you describe when looking at Salvador Dali's works in Figueres but cant find such examples easily although the painting versions by Picasso Dali Langdon et al are illustrated here http://ideate.xsead.cmu.edu/gallery/projects/hidden-word-illusions since you have explained your desire to generate these text via tex I am adding to your title you can change it back if you wish

Comment: @KJO: That's perfectly fine! Good to know. Glad this post evolves.

Comment: I can explain what those numbers from `dvitype` mean, but they won't be helpful for you, I think — `setchar72 h:=1310720+491521=1802241, hh:=114` means that the command in the DVI file is to set the character H. The effect of this command (apart from putting the character H at the “current” position) is to change the current position's horizontal offset (`h`) to the right by the width of the char 72 (H) in the current font metrics, from 1310720 to 1310720+491521=1802241. (The units are certain tiny units; I believe 10^-7 m but I forget…) And `hh` is the rounded value in pixels, for chosen DPI.

Comment: More fundamentally, the question does not make sense for typical text typeset by TeX, because it uses variable-width characters and spaces. So firstly you need to restrict to fixed-width font, with moreover fixed-width spaces. That is easily arranged. But if you have such text then you don't need to go via the output of TeX (`dvitype`) to determine character positions, because they are determined in a simple way from the input itself… almost. When you say multi-column text, what support are you looking for from TeX? Are you willing to manually decide what text goes into what column?

Comment: Hi @ShreevatsaR and thanks a lot for your valuable contribution! Helped me a lot in digging further into the problem. Honestly, I don't know how to set the font size to fixed width, but it helps to know that this is technically possible. But is it really that simple to do the mapping from given text to individual character positions? No idea how. An answer to this problem is highly appreciated. Do you know, by the way, if it is possible to set a character for a given font to bold. And do you know if it is going to take the same amount of space than a regular character?

Comment: @MaxHerrmann There exist fixed-width (pairs of) fonts, in which every character, regular or bold, takes the same width. But you didn't answer what you meant by multi-column text? Can you add an example to the question? Because what I meant by computing the position from the text is that (assuming a single column of text) it's something that can even be done outside TeX, given just the text. Is my understanding of your problem correct?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer just a form of Proof Of Concept for one possible approach ??
There must be many other potential answers as seen in some of the "fun" answers on this site.

Using some input for the overlay (in this case a figlet font) we could start with this as input

```
  .##......##..........##..##................##.......##..................##.......##
  .##......##..........##..##................##.......##..................##.......##
  .##......##..#####...##..##..######........##...#...##..######..######..##.......##
  .##########.##...##..##..##.##....##.......##..###..##.##....##..##..#..##...######
  .##......##.#######..##..##.##....##.......##.##.##.##.##....##..##.....##..##...##
  .##......##.##.......##..##.##....##.......####...####.##....##..##.....##..##...##
  .##......##..######.###.###..######........##.......##..######..###.....###..######
```

Then it would be very simple to replace the # like this

```
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf...........\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.................\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf...................\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf...........\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.................\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf...................\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.........\textbf.\textbf....\textbf....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf...\textbf...\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf......\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.....\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf......\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf....\textbf.\textbf.
  .\textbf.\textbf.......\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.\textbf..\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.........\textbf.\textbf........\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf......\textbf.\textbf.\textbf...\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.\textbf.
```

OR perhaps **.** for use with \usepackage{easyformat}

[EDIT]

I have removed my poor results for the above since Phelype has now taken that idea much further.

At this point I am unsure in what context this may work since if I apply it how I initially saw it, then it needs a greater emphasis than simply "bold " to work.

See w**h**at th**e** embo**l**dened **p**aragraph **m**ay contain b**e**low ?

[image][image]

Comment: It's a good idea! You could define an environment that makes `.` and `#` both active, and one print a normal dot and the other a bold dot, both with the same width :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks my tex skills are very limited for defining any environment other than DOS I can of course always cut paste and modify as seen here :-)

Comment: May I add an answer with that?

Comment: The challenge is yours I will delete my POC if anyone can replace or better it

Comment: Not exactly better, just simplified the input :)

Comment: That's a very valid replacement for my concept I might wait a couple of upvotes and see if I can get my next badge (disciplined= get 3 votes then delete own answer :-)

Comment: Wow KJO! How did you manage to highlight thos characters in a controlled fashion?! Sorry to say, that I cannot read the hidden mesage. Maybe printing a white character on a black box would do the trick.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann they were done the old fashioned way like half a century ago when we overstruck by hand. The problem I was trying to highlight was that with a small percentage of black on a white field (or reverse white on black should be similar) due to proportions there is only just a small difference in contrast hence the stenographic use (it is so subtle it would probably need a machine to spot it) It would be more noticeable if the underlying characters have no spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Using KJO's idea and simplifying the input:

You can use an environment, say, `steganography` which makes two characters active and define those two characters to print a dot and a bold dot.

Here's a very crude approach to demonstrate (using `.` and `#` as in KJO's example):

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\stegchar=.
\newlength\stegVspace  \stegVspace=4\p@
\newlength\stegHspace  \stegHspace=3\p@
\newenvironment{steganography}{%
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \catcode`\#=\active
  \obeylines
  \baselineskip=\stegVspace
  \@steganography
}{}
\begingroup
\catcode`\.=\active
\catcode`\#=\active
\gdef\@steganography{%
  \def.{\leavevmode\hb@xt@\stegHspace{\hss\stegchar\hss}}%
  \def#{\leavevmode\hb@xt@\stegHspace{\hss\textbf{\stegchar}\hss}}%
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{steganography}
  .##......##..........##..##................##.......##..................##.......##
  .##......##..........##..##................##.......##..................##.......##
  .##......##..#####...##..##..######........##...#...##..######..######..##.......##
  .##########.##...##..##..##.##....##.......##..###..##.##....##..##..#..##...######
  .##......##.#######..##..##.##....##.......##.##.##.##.##....##..##.....##..##...##
  .##......##.##.......##..##.##....##.......####...####.##....##..##.....##..##...##
  .##......##..######.###.###..######........##.......##..######..###.....###..######
\end{steganography}

\end{document}
```